Selenium Webdriver can't find popup window element by ID
I have a webpage and I want to click the button with ID btnAddConfirmOk. This button is in the tree structure like this:

However, this button will not get clicked no matter what I do... I am trying to do it like this in my class:
int t = 5000;

Thread.Sleep(t);
this.getSubElement(
    Driver,
    By.Id(
        "btnAddConfirmOk"
    )
).Click();
Thread.Sleep(t);


Note:
I use sleep to make sure that page is updated before button is clicked. This button then spans a popup window. This button is part of the popup window, but I was able to click other elements in this popup window just fine...

And this is my getSubElement() function that waits for the element for 50 seconds:
        private IWebElement getSubElement<T>(T element, By subelement, double timeout = 50000)
        {
            if (typeof(T) != typeof(IWebElement) && typeof(T) != typeof(WindowsApplicationDriver.WindowsDriver) && typeof(T) != typeof(IWebDriver))
            {
                Assert.Fail("getSubElement(): Only accepting elements of types IWebElement/WindowsDriver.\n");
            }

            if (timeout > 50000)
            {
                Assert.Fail("getSubElement(): Max allowed timeout is 50000.\n");
            }

            bool iterate = true;
            IWebElement subElement = null;
            System.Timers.Timer timer;

            using (timer = new System.Timers.Timer())
            {
                timer.Interval = timeout;
                timer.Elapsed += timerExpired;
                timer.Start();

                while (iterate == true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // We cast general type T to specific type.
                        if (typeof(T) == typeof(IWebElement))
                        {
                            subElement = ((IWebElement)(object)element).FindElement(subelement);
                        }
                        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(WindowsApplicationDriver.WindowsDriver))
                        {
                            subElement = ((WindowsApplicationDriver.WindowsDriver)(object)element).FindElement(subelement);
                        }
                        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(IWebDriver))
                        {
                            subElement = ((IWebDriver)(object)element).FindElement(subelement);
                        }
                        iterate = false;
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchElementException)
                    {
                        // Do nothing.
                    }
                }
                timer.Stop();
                timer.Dispose();
            }
            return subElement;
        }

To me, everything looks correct and this system works for all other elements which I also reference by their ID. However it does not work for this one.

looks like there's a space in the id value... use xpath of //buton(@name="AddConfirmOk"), or //button(@id="btn AddConfirmOk")  Don't think that getSubElement method is needed at all, but doesn't look like you call it correctly unless there's overloaded args...

I found the reason! HTML/CSS does not limit you to have two identical id and this is exactly what was happening to me. I was targetting the wrong id all along. Oh these developers... I read this wonderful article (link) where I found out that I can use "Chrome dev tools" to see if the correct element is targeted. I just had to open "Chrome dev tools" with F12 and then press CTRL+F to open a search bar where Xpaths can be searched and are highlighted if located. Neat!
